# Android UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I've recieved a large number of exceptions reported within Google Play Developer console for an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` that I'm struggling to reproduce or make worthy sense of the logged details, which are:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
  at md58bc2f6e10eea2f0547a25d785bacc4b2.GlobalApplication.n_onCreate (Native Method)
  at md58bc2f6e10eea2f0547a25d785bacc4b2.GlobalApplication.onCreate (GlobalApplication.java:25)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1028)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:5659)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2 (ActivityThread.java)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1637)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:156)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6524)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:941)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:831)
```

Looking online it sounds like there's a missing native library, although I don't know which one or how to determine that!

Does anyone have any ideas of what could be causing this, from the `GlobalApplication.OnCreate`?

Comment: It seems `Google Play Developer` reported the bug with device info, check them `abi` whether the same. Also check all `System.LoadLibrary("xxxxx")` inside `GlobalApplication.OnCreate`.

Comment: Hi sakiM. The device was a Mate 9 Pro, the same device I use myself and never had a problem. The ABI listed on Google Play Developer for this device are arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a and armeabi. I've compiled for armeabi-v7a. There are no System.LoadLibrary calls within GlobalApplication.OnCreate that I can find. Do you know how to dig deeper into that method?

Comment: Could you extract the apk to confirm whether there were only `/lib/armeabi-v7a` in `/lib`? Seems there was something wrong with xamarin abi config or you didn't have all the `arm64-v8a` *.so libs. Add `ndk { abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"}` to `build.gradle`, under `android` -> `defaultConfig` block may help.

Comment: I've encountered this issue again. I can confirm that the extracted APK has only 'armeabi-v7a' within the libs folder..

Comment: Hi, @Le-royStaines! did you have any success on this issue? i faced it too :(

Comment: @SamSch I don't know! But we don't seem to have this issue since I updated all references and targeted the latest OS version.

Comment: @Le-royStaines ok, thanks!